# why the form element generated in each .aspx page?

Tags: .net, asp.net, webforms

I am new in asp.net,I have to luanch our application use asp.net,and I use the visial studio,I just found that each time I create a new page,there will be something like:

```
<body>
  <form runat="server">
   the content of my page
  </form>
</body>
```

I just do not know why the form element exist in EVERY page,some of them does not need a form at all,since I do not try to submit something to the server side use the form.

WHy?

Comment: Possible repeat of similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530120/how-to-get-rid-of-the-default-form-element-from-a-aspx-page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original ASP.Net (Webforms) framework made some assumptions about how you would work.  Some of these can be annoying now, depending how you like to work.

- Most .Net controls require a form.
- ViewState requires a form, and *only* one form.
- the Postback model requires a form, and *only* one form.

Most asp.net functionality would not work if there wasn't a form.  So not having a form **by default** would cause a lot of problems, especially for beginners.  The first step on almost every page would be to drag over your "form container control" or whatever it would be called, and people would get it wrong all the time.  Given their plan, a *one form that was always there* made sense.

This discussion assumes **Webforms**, the "default" ASP.NET web framework.  In ASP.Net MVC, there is no automatic form element.  A lot of assumptions like this one are traded for **other assumptions**, which many of us now prefer.

Comment: A form around the whole page hurts a **lot** when you want to have multiple separate forms in the page. I've seen enough people cursing Web Forms as a result of that to never want to go near the thing.

Comment: @David  It sounds like you and these others would be happier with ASP.NET MVC, as am I.  What I explained above was this single form's necessity as part of WebForms.  Like you, I prefer more control, more ajax, and fewer assumptions about how I want to work.

Comment: @David, actually it sounds like you're simply doing it wrong. See my answer where I explain how you're supposed to handle multiple logical forms within the page.

Answer (score 4):

ASP.Net requires that all server controls be nested within a form control. This is because ASP.net stores it's state information in a hidden control called `ViewState`. Any server controls you have on your page will use `ViewState` to persist their state. Also, you should be aware that you may only have one form on the page.

If you need to have two separate "forms," you would generally place each one in a Panel control and set it's `DefaultButton` property and the `ValidationGroup` property on it's elements in order to isolate it from the other "forms."

Please see [ASP.NET Web Forms from W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_forms.asp) for more information.

Comment: +1, good summary, coupled with good hints about how to work around this limitation of the framework.