# ASPX EventValidation error with DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, webforms

This must have an obvious solution, but I'm stumped. We are developing an application which is mostly `XHR`-based, so while we are using `.aspx`, very little is done with typical controls. However, in a few spots, we are just doing basic "throw this data into a spreadsheet for the user" things with a couple dropdowns for timespan for reports, etc.

The problem is when we use `asp:DropDownList` controls, it immediately causes any page we put them in to throw Event Validation errors on submit. I have created test pages that do not share the rest of the application's master pages (aka, no JS at all modifying things client side) just to be sure that we don't have some stray JS causing issues.

If I remove the `DropDownList` in the following example, the button click happens just fine. If I click the button with the page sitting as shown, it throws the `Event Validation error`.

*However*, other applications running on the same machine, in 4.0 Integrated app pools, do not exhibit this behavior, so I'm assuming it has something to do with the configuration. The `web.config` is pretty standard...tried turning `httpCompression` section off in a desperate attempt, but to no avail.

Does anyone have a suggestion on where to start here? Please remember... There is **NO CLIENT SIDE MODIFICATION** going on. This is straight from the server to the browser, then 'click' on the ASP-generated button.

Turning off Event Validation in the page directive does eliminate the error, but I'd rather not turn off validation if I can help it.

**Environment**:

- Windows 7 Pro
- IIS 7.5
- .NET 4.0 Integrated app-pool
- Error happens in IE9/Chrome/Firefox/Safari

**Page**:

```
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDays" runat="server">
            <asp:ListItem Text="30 Days" Value="30"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="60 Days" Value="60"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="90 Days" Value="90"></asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="butExport" Text="Export" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Codebehind**:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    butExport.Click += new EventHandler(butExport_Click);
}

void butExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Syslog("clicked");
}
```

**Form Data (according to Chrome Inspector)**:

- __VIEWSTATE:/wEPDwULLTIwOTUzNjUzOTVkZIiv1cdholWibyWL8h5HASwxedB47NUpctCv8OQc1CWM
- __EVENTVALIDATION:/wEWAgL0voCyDQKDgcL6CAX34hdaRiHyNiY1xLIh5Pr6aj5q8h8gGG875vMq1SXF
- ddlDays:30
- butExport:Export

Comment: Try to use  EnableEventValidation="False"

Comment: Peretz, I did state in my question that the error DOES go away when I turn off event validation, but that does eliminate a "free" security feature ASP.NET offers, and we would prefer to not turn that off. Thanks for the input, though.

Comment: if the button is doing the post back since its a asp control, is there a need for the <form>?

Comment: Two Questions:Do you have set the machine key on web.config ? Do you have try to set the EventHandler on Init ? - or just place it direct on the button.

Comment: @Aristos - I have tried attaching the event handler on the button in the aspx (aka `onClick="butExport_click"`) in other pages with the same result. I just attempted to attach it programmatically in Page_Init, but that did not change anything either. I do have a `machineKey` element in my `web.config` set to AutoGenerate

Comment: I've pushed the application to one of our staging machines as well, setup on it's own app-pool (.NET 4.0 Integrated) and it exhibits the same problems, so it doesn't seem to be machine specific. Also another dev in the office has the same problem on his development box.

Comment: @EricRobinson, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/530120/how-to-get-rid-of-the-default-form-element-from-a-aspx-page?rq=1 regarding the need for the form element.

Comment: It works in my env, ASP.NET 4.0.

Comment: Yeah, it works in a new project I created on the same machine as well. It occurred to me that maybe Global.asax or our HTTPHandler is interfering. Will try to check on that tomorrow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I started going through my project looking for any possible configuration item that could be causing issues. Turns out a co-worker used a `WebControlAdapter` and applied it to all `DropDownLists` and during the Render, did not use `RegisterForEventValidation`.

I don't particularly like the adapter, but in the interest of moving on with life, I left it there and while rendering bound items, I'm calling `Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation` for each value. This has fixed every problematic `DropDownList` we have in the application.

Thanks for the suggestions, all.